# What is the relation between APP_PLATFORM, android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm developing an Android app that uses NDK features. My app defines `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `APP_PLATFORM` in jni/Application.mk.

My current understanding is that `android:minSdkVersion` decalres minimal supported OS version, `android:targetSdkVersion` declares Java library version to be linked against, and `APP_PLATFORM` declares C++ library to be linked against.

Two questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is it Ok for `APP_PLATFORM` to be greater that `android:minSdkVersion`? Or they must be equal each other?

The reason for my question: I want my app to be available for devices with **API >= 10**, but I need to use NDK functions (like `AMotionEvent_getAxisValue`) that are defined in `platforms\android-13` folder in NDK. So I use `android:minSdkVersion=10` and `APP_PLATFORM=13`. Project compiles successfully, but would it be runnable on API 10-12 devices?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. `android:minSdkVersion` is the minimum OS version that your app expects.
2. `android:targetSdkVersion` is essentially the maximum OS version that you've designed your app to work with. Here's an example of how this works. Imagine that you tested your app fine with API 19 and you release your app with `android:targetSdkVersion`=19. Then Google decides to release API 20 with a change in behavior of some API, but they don't want to change the behavior for old apps (to prevent from breaking them). So when your app starts up, Android sees that your app has `targetSdkVersion`=19, so it gives you the old API behavior, but if some other app says `targetSdkVersion`=20, Android will give it the new API behavior.
3. `APP_PLATFORM` is the version of the native headers and libraries that the NDK will compile your native code with. If you set `APP_PLATFORM` to a specific value and you use APIs that are only available in that platform version, then your app will not run properly on older platforms. So `APP_PLATFORM` is a minimum value. The solution is to use a lower value and not use those newer APIs, or to write code that decides at runtime whether to call the new APIs or not (and probably use `dlopen`/`dlsym`).

It seems like in general it doesn't make sense to use an `APP_PLATFORM` value newer than `android:minSdkVersion`, unless you're doing some special (like being careful not to call new APIs by checking the version at runtime, plus making sure not to link to new APIs and instead using `dlopen`/`dlsym`).

So if you use `APP_PLATFORM=13` and you call `AMotionEvent_getAxisValue` (which is not in earlier platform headers, implying that it isn't available at runtime on earlier platforms), your app will not run on devices with API < 13. The one caveat would be if `AMotionEvent_getAxisValue` is actually available on older versions, but it just wasn't in the header/library files or it just wasn't documented. But I don't know if that's the case for this particular API (basically, that would require more research and risk analysis of whether you want to depend on something unsupported).

Comment: Thanks. But there is another version specifier: What about 4. project.properties 'target=android-xx' ?

Comment: @Bram That's the one that actually determines which version of the Android library your (Java) code is built against. It's equivalent to APP_PLATFORM but for non-native code. If you don't specify APP_PLATFORM, it defaults to the value set in project.properties.

Comment: Note that for native code, you don't necessarily have to use new APIs for your code to be incompatible with older Android versions. Just setting APP_PLATFORM too high can result in the compiler deciding to use primitives that don't exist (e.g. if APP_PLATFORM >= 24, calling std::vector::resize maxe the compiler produce code that doesn't work on Lollipop). In short, it's dangerous to ever have APP_PLATFORM higher than minSdkVersion (and since it defaults to the SDK version you're building non-native code for, you should always set it explicitly).

Comment: Cool example Karu.  I included that in a roundup answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41079462/1046167

Answer (score 39):

This answer brings together hard-to-find but important information from many excellent websites and stackoverflow answers/comments on this under-documented NDK subject:

## Avoiding Crashes: NDK Version, `minSdKVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `APP_PLATFORM` (in project.properties)

### The short version

To prevent your native Android app from mysteriously crashing on older customer devices, the short answer is to make your NDK `APP_PLATFORM` (in `project.properties` or `Application.mk`) the same as your `minSdkVersion` (in `AndroidManifest.xml`).

But depending on what NDK features you use, doing so may severely limit the set of customers who can download your app.

To find out why that is and whether you have other options, read on...

### Four different concepts

- **NDK Version** (e.g. r10e, r13b): this is the version of the Android NDK release (the tar/zip file) you download from Google.  [Here are all the NDK versions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html)
- **`minSdkVersion`** (e.g. 15,19,21) is a setting you make in your AndroidManifest.xml in a [`<uses-sdk>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) element under the `<manifest>` element.  This setting affects both NDK (native) and Java development.
- **`targetSdkVersion`** (e.g. 15,19,21) is a different setting you make in your AndroidManifest.xml in a [`<uses-sdk>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) element under the `<manifest>` element.  This setting affects only Java development.
- **`APP_PLATFORM`** (e.g. 15,19,21) is a setting you make in your Native NDK project.  Typically this setting is found in the `project.properties` file at the root of your project as the last number at the end of the `target=` line, e.g. `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:21` for level 21 (and usually the way that "21" got there is by being the `-t/--target` option to a command-line invocation of the `android create project` or `android update project` command). You can also make this setting by putting `APP_PLATFORM := android-21` into your `Application.mk` file.

### Three of these concepts use API Level Numbers

`minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `APP_PLATFORM` use Android's consistent numbering scheme for API levels:

[Click here to see Google's API Level Chart](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

As you can see, the levels roughly correspond to Android releases, but do not even remotely match the number of the Android release (that would be too easy).  For example, API level 10 corresponds to Android OS 2.3.3 and 2.3.4.

The cute code-names like "Lollipop" and "Nougat" are at a coarser granularity than API versions.  For example, several API versions (21 and 22) are "Lollipop"

These same API version numbers are encoded by the Java `Build.VERSION_CODES` type:

[Click here to see Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

For example, level 22 is `LOLLIPOP_MR1`

Not every number exists for each concept.  For example, you might want to support API level 10, but there is no `APP_PLATFORM` 10 so you would go back to the last available `APP_PLATFORM`, `APP_PLATFORM` 9.

[Click here to see distribution of API versions in the installed base in the wild](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

### What is `minSdkVersion`?

This setting is by far the easiest to understand.  When you set `minSdkVersion` to, say, 21 (corresponding to Android OS 5.0), that means that the Google Play Store will only advertise your app as supporting Android OS 5.0 and beyond, and Android will prevent users from installing your app if their Android device has lower than Android OS 5.0 installed.

So `minSdkVersion` is the lowest OS you support.  Nice and simple.

This setting obviously has implications both for Java and C code: you want to set it to the lowest OS version that both parts of your code can support.

Both `targetSdkVersion` and `APP_PLATFORM` must be greater than or equal to `minSdkVersion`.

### What is `targetSdkVersion`?

This setting only has effect in the Android Java world (it has no effect on your C NDK code).  Its fulfills a purpose in the Android Java world that is similar to  `APP_PLATFORM` in the Android C NDK world.

Sometimes you want your app to support older devices, but also use new features only available on newer Java API versions.

For example, Android added a nifty Java [`VoiceInteractor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/VoiceInteractor.html) API that's only supported in API 23 (Android 6.0) or later.  You might want to support `VoiceInteractor` if your customers have a new device, but still have your app run on older devices.

By setting `targetSdkVersion` to 23, you are making a simple contract with Android:

- Android agrees to give your app code access to API-23-only Java features like `VoiceInteractor`
- In return, you agree to check, at runtime in your Java code, whether that feature is available on the customer's device before calling it (otherwise your app will crash).

This contract works because in Java, it is "ok" if your code has references to classes/methods that might not exist on the customer's device, as long as you don't call them.

The contract applies to all Android Java features added after your `minSdkVersion` up to and including your `targetSdkVersion`.

In addition to giving you access to certain new Java APIs, the `targetSdkVersion` setting also enables or disables certain well-documented compatibility behaviors:

[Click here to see which behavior changes come with each `targetSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

These well-documented changes also form a kind of contract.  For example, around Android 4, Google migrated their Android device designs away from having a dedicated menu button and towards having an on-screen Action bar.  If your app has a `targetSdkVersion` lower than 14 (Android 4.0.1), Google would put a software menu button up on the screen to make sure your app kept working even if the device didn't have a dedicated menu button.   But by choosing a `targetSdkVersion` greater than or equal to 14 at build time, you are promising Google that you either don't have a menu or you use an Action bar, so Google no longer puts up the software menu button.

### What is `APP_PLATFORM`?

`APP_PLATFORM` performs a similar function in the C NDK world that `targetSdkVersion` performs in the Java world.

But, sadly, due to a combination of limitations in the C language and bad behavior by Google, `APP_PLATFORM` is significantly more dangerous and, frankly, nearly unusable.

Let's start from the beginning...

`APP_PLATFORM` is an NDK-only setting that tells the `build-ndk` tool which subdirectory of your NDK to look in for certain key include files and libraries which collectively are referred to as an NDK "platform."  Each NDK distribution (each NDK tar/zip that we developers [download from Google](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html)) contains multiple platforms.

For example, if you set `APP_PLATFORM` to `android-21`, `build-ndk` will look in:

```
$(ndk_directory)/platforms/android-21/arch-$(architecture)/usr/include
$(ndk_directory)/platforms/android-21/arch-$(architecture)/usr/lib
```

for include files and libraries.

If you installed your NDK by simply downloading a zip/tar from [Google's NDK Downloads Website](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html), then `$(ndk_directory)` is simply the directory where you extracted the file.

If you installed your NDK by first downloading the Android (Java) SDK and then running the Android SDK Manager to install the "NDK" item, then $(ndk_directory) is `$(sdk_directory)/ndk-bundle`, where `$(sdk_directory)` is wherever your SDK is installed.

`$(architecture)` is `arm`, `arm64`, `x86`, etc.

### What is in a "platform"?

The `$(ndk_directory)/platforms/android-XX` directory contains two super-important things:

- all your C library calls like `fopen()`, `atof()`, `sprintf()` etc.  The C library on Android is called "bionic."
- Android-specific NDK calls/types/defines like `AInputQueue` and `EGLContext`

### What changes at different `APP_PLATFORM` levels?

In each `android-XX` version, Google adds more calls to the NDK.  For example,

- `APP_PLATFORM` API level 9 added the very useful [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html)
- `APP_PLATFORM` API level 18 added OpenGL ES 3.0

Some `APP_PLATFORM` versions also add calls to the C library, and/or "fix" things that are missing (for example, the token `PTHREAD_KEYS_MAX` got added in `APP_PLATFORM` 21).

[Click here to read Google's incomplete documentation on what changed in each `APP_PLATFORM` level](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html)

So far this is similar to the Java world.  Nobody expects Google or any other OS vendor to make every new feature available on old devices, especially when those features rely on hardware only found on newer devices (e.g. faster processors, new camera features, new audio features).

But Google's NDK team did a naughty thing that the Java team did not.

In some `APP_PLATFORM` versions, Google made gratuitous, breaking API changes that **cannot possibly be excused by any legitimate argument** such as those above.

These are the types of breaking API changes that Android Java developers would never accept.  For example, Google has

- **renamed C library functions** and
- changed C library functions **from being inlined to being not inlined**

The most serious case of this was `APP_PLATFORM` 21, where Google made many breaking changes that generated an extremely high number of stackoverflow issues (many examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194260/android-ndk-and-newer-api-support) and more below).

But there also have been changes in previous `APP_PLATFORM`s (e.g. `signal()` in [API 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374114/is-it-possible-to-use-the-latest-app-platform-while-still-maintaining-backward-c)).

And there are even some breaking changes in `APP_PLATFORM`s after 21 such as `APP_PLATFORM` 24 (e.g. `std::vector::resize` as Karu mentions in a comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888052/what-is-the-relation-between-app-platform-androidminsdkversion-and-androidtar)).

So this is clearly a bad Google habit that is here to stay.

### Why do these changes make my app crash on old devices?

To see why these naughty changes are a problem, remember that the C library on Android is a **shared library**, meaning that the implementation of non-inline, non-macro calls like `sprintf()` is not compiled into your program but rather present in the C library on your test devices and on each customer device.

So it doesn't just matter what API version you have in your development environment.  It also matters what API version of C library is on each device where your app might run.

Suppose your app calls `atof()` and you build your app with `APP_PLATFORM` 21 and test it on your modern test devices that run Android 5 or later (API version 21 or later).  Everything looks ok.

Then you release your app and suddenly find tons of customers with Android OS versions 4.4 and earlier (API versions less than 21) report your app crashing on their devices.

What's going on?

In `APP_PLATFORM` 21 (Android 5), `atof()` is a regular (not `inline`, not macro) function.  So the native part of your app (the `myapp.so` file that `ndk-build` will create, and that you load from your Java code using `System.loadLibrary("myapp")`) will be marked as having a dependency on an external function called atof() in the C library.

When you run your app on a given device, Android will open your `myapp.so`, see the dependency on `atof()`, and find `atof()` in the C library on that device.

But the shock surprise is that in `APP_PLATFORM`s earlier than 21, `atof()` was an `inline` function in the platform header files, meaning that:

- its implementation (its definition, its code, its body) was in the header file and got compiled into your app when you built your app
- there is no `atof()` implementation in the C library on any customer device with API < 21 (any customer device running Android < 5).  There never needed to be, since `atof()` was inline back in those days.

So when you run your app on devices running API version < 21 (Android OS < 5), the Java call `System.loadLibrary("myapp")` fails because the run-time loader cannot find all the symbols needed by your `myapp.so`.  Android knows your `myapp.so` needs `atof()` but cannot find `atof()` in the C library on the device.  Crash.

This `atof()` example is only one of many, undocumented or barely-documented breaking changes that Google brazenly refers to as [WorkingAsIntended](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73725).  Besides 
[`atof()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571399/android-ndk-cant-find-atof-function), you can find huge numbers of other stackoverflow items with the same cause (e.g. with [`mkfifo()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091001/how-to-use-mkfifo-using-androids-ndk/27093163#27093163) and, unbelievably, even [`rand()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338318/cannot-load-library-reloc-library1285-cannot-locate-rand/27338365#27338365))

### How can I fix it?

In the `atof()` example above, you might say to yourself "okay, if there is no `atof()` on older devices, I'll provide one in my app and ship a new app version."

And in fact that would work.

But you'll have a sinking feeling in your stomach when you realize there is no answer to a much more important question:

### How can I know what changed, and what old devices will be affected?

Here's the real kicker.  **You can't.**

Unlike the Android Java API, where Google carefully maintains backwards compatibility with old APIs, clearly documenting any behavior changes that are keyed to the `targetSdkVersion` parameters, **there is no such documentation** for
Android NDK `APP_PLATFORM` levels.

Like the Java API, you can look up an NDK call and find out what is the earliest API version (the earliest customer Android OS) where that call is supported.

But unlike the Java API with `targetSdkVersion`, when you change your NDK `APP_PLATFORM` level, you will not be able to find any Google documentation that tells you:

- what API changes (possibly even C library API changes) exist that might break your app on older devices.  For example, a list of functions like `atof()`, `mkfifo()` and `rand()` for which you would need to provide your own implementation for older devices
- what effect not providing those re-implemented routines will have on the lowest Android OS that you can now support with your app

Simply put, Google won't tell you the earliest Android version that each `APP_PLATFORM` supports.

If you happen to have a lot of old devices lying around and a **lot** of time, you could try your app on every possible old Android version and see what crashes with missing C library symbols, providing custom implementations for functions that are not found.  Of course that's only the first level of testing: in reality Google could have made breaking changes where the symbol is still there (so no crash), but the call behaves differently.  This would never be accepted at the Java level but for some reason Google feels entitled to do it with the NDK.

Of course, nobody has time to do this, nor should developers have to.

So effectively what that means is that this is the official Google NDK policy:

> Every time you increase the `APP_PLATFORM` of your project, you get access to new APIs, but you also get some breaking changes that will cause your app to crash on some older devices.  Oh, and we're not going to give you a specific list of those changes.  Nor are we going to tell you the earliest Android OS version on which your app is still guaranteed to work.

And effectively what **that** means is:

> Every time you increase the `APP_PLATFORM` of your project, you have to set `minSdkVersion` equal to `APP_PLATFORM`, **preventing your app from running on older devices**.  Otherwise your app may crash on some older devices.

It is hard to overstate how tragic this is.

Google is effectively telling you "in order to use new NDK features, you must abandon all your customers with old devices and abandon future sales to customers with older devices."

To make this tragedy concrete with a real-world example, notice that Google added support for OpenGL ES 3.1 in [API Level 21 (Android OS 5.0)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#a18).  Suppose you wanted to support new OpenGL ES 3.1 features on new devices, but still support OpenGL ES 3.0 ([API level 18 (Android OS 4.3)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#a18)) and OpenGL ES 2.0 ([API level 5 (Android OS 2.0)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#a5)) on older devices.  This is a very likely scenario since (unlike the transition from OpenGL ES 1 to 2) the changes in OpenGL ES 2 to 3 are quite minor and cumulative.

In order to support ES 3.1 from your app with Google's absurd NDK policy, you would have to drop support for all devices with less than Android 5.

### Are there workarounds?

Kind of, but it's unlikely any developer has the time for them.

The first workaround was mentioned above: carefully test your app on every possible old Android version, not only for symbol-not-found crashes but behavior changes too.

The second workaround is that you can, in theory, "ship" different versions of your NDK code to customers with different API versions.

The easiest way is probably do that at the NDK level.  For example, you could build multiple `myapp.so`s in your NDK build, each with a different `APP_PLATFORM` value in Application.mk, and bundle all of them into your app `.apk`.  Then from  your Java code you could `System.LoadLibrary()` a different `.so` depending on the API version of the customer's device.

This would be similar *in structure* to how NDK developers currently bundle multiple NDK versions for each architecture (e.g. `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `mips`, `x86`).

However, there is a **massive** practical difference: unlike the multiple ABIs which `ndk-build` more or less provides for free without wasting developer time, the developer would have to spend a lot of time hacking both the NDK and Java build scripts to create and distribute multiple `APP_PLATFORM` `.so` versions.
Then every time developers change their C code, they must carefully consider how each function they call behaves (if it even exists) in each API version.  This kind of work is totally expected and acceptable for calls that relate directly to new hardware features, but it is totally ridiculous that Android's NDK team makes us do this for calls like `atof()` and `rand()`.

The third workaround is the one I suspect most developers do: fix problems as angry customers report them, and **pray** that there are not more such crashes to come (or causing customers to give their apps bad reviews and never reporting the issue to the developer).

### dlsym() is a non-workaround

You might compare the C NDK `APP_PLATFORM` compatibility issue to the much cleaner Java `targetSdkVersion` and say

> "hey, if I can set `targetSdkVersion` and then check for new features at runtime in Java, can't I set `APP_PLATFORM` and check for new features in runtime at C?"

Well, no.

The first problem is that in order to do this in C, unlike in Java, you have to refrain from even referencing the routine in your code.  Then you'd have to open the C library with `dlopen()` and try to extract the routine you want with `dlsym()`.  Let's not even get into the likelihood of vendor device-dependency even finding the C library.  Plus the complexity that due to Android breaking changes, some routines have [changed name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194260/android-ndk-and-newer-api-support) so even the name you look up would have to depend on the API version of the device.

But the second, worse problem is that sometimes you are not the one making the call.  As we will explain just below, the compiler may insert calls to routines that Google has broken, like `stpcpy()` and `std::vector::resize`, and you are not in a position to replace these invocations with a call to `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.  The only way to prevent the compiler from calling them is to reduce `APP_PLATFORM`, and this defeats the purpose of accessing new features on compatible devices.

### Would having a list of changed calls help?

Amazingly, no. The problem is even worse than it sounds.

Let's say hypothetically Google **did** publish a complete list of all routines like `atof()` with breaking changes.  You could just scan your code for those routines, and if you don't call them, you're safe, right?

Wrong.

It turns out that sometimes the bleeding **compiler** will call those breaking-changes routines without them actually appearing in your code:

- if you build to `APP_PLATFORM` 21 (Android 5) and run on older devices (Android <5), you may be shocked to see crashes because the older devices cannot find  `stpcpy()`, a routine you never call.  It turns out the compiler will notice certain `stpcpy()`-like patterns in your code and replace them with a call to `stpcpy()`!  This can be seen in many stackoverflow examples: [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509779/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-compiling-with-api21) [example 2](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/issues/298) [example 3](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/commit/94648396751ec461fc5bc9b6887abe8f0d4bcb09) [example 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977355/cannot-locate-symbol-stpcpy-using-qtds-driver-on-android).  If you attempt to implement `stpcpy()` yourself for backwards compatibility, you will get an infinite loop unless you are clever enough to implement it in a [sufficiently non-`stpcpy()` way](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79343)!  Insanity.
- if you build to `APP_PLATFORM` 24 you will encounter a similar problem with `std::vector::resize` as Karu mentions in a comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888052/what-is-the-relation-between-app-platform-androidminsdkversion-and-androidtar)).

In both cases, the compiler decides it can insert these calls because it inspects the set of include files you are using---your `APP_PLATFORM`---and decides the calls are available.  You can't reduce `APP_PLATFORM` without losing access to the new routines you want to use on new devices.  Catch-22.

### How could Google get away with this?

Summarizing the above, Google's effective NDK policy is:

> Every time you increase the `APP_PLATFORM` of your project, you have to set `minSdkVersion` equal to `APP_PLATFORM`, **preventing your app from running on older devices**, unless you are willing to do massive exhaustive testing on old devices, or pray.

I could never actually find an official Google policy statement to this effect.  Google's official documentation says exactly the opposite.  In particular, this passage from [Google's official NDK Levels documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#mnu) is utter nonsense:

> Each new release of NDK headers and libraries for a given Android API level is cumulative; you are nearly always safe if you use the most recently released headers when building your app. For example, you can use the NDK headers for Android API level 21 for an app targeting API level 16. By doing so, however, you increase your APK's footprint.

In fact the exact opposite is true: it is imperative that you use API level 16 headers to target API level 16 devices, otherwise your app will crash if you use one of a large set of APIs like `atof()` with undocumented breaking changes.

About the most help we ever got from Google was a cryptic NDK build warning `WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-XX is larger than android:minSdkVersion` without any associated documentation that I could find.

I hope this answer has been eye-opening and helpful for developers, and perhaps as we increase awareness amongst developers it might motivate the Google NDK developers to respect backwards compatibility as much as the Google Java developers do.

*References:* many, many links to other stackoverflow answers and other webpages are interleaved in the text above.

Comment: FWIW, it does seem like Google are working on improving this situation, in the form of a feature they call "Unified Headers". See https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/120 and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md for info on the feature, and https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/113 for a discussion on the matter. Currently it seems to be planned to be included in NDK r14.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  I looked at them but it's still unclear whether the "Unified Headers" project really has anything to do with backwards compatibility: the ability for an app that uses, say, android-15 to change to using android-21 to get some new features but also have the old features still work on older devices with Android versions as far back as API level 15.  That is the basic meaning of "backwards compatibility" in the Android Java world and pretty much any other world, but it doesn't seem to be a priority for the NDK team.

Comment: As far as I know, that is the intention, although I haven't explored it fully. It will be one single set of headers that will include all features, and you'll tell it what your minimum version is, and will behave accordingly. I'm not sure if it will completely hide all newer functionality though, or if it will keep new functionality available (which you'd need to use with care, e.g. `dlsym` or whatnot). At least it should switch the tricky functions (`rand` etc) to the version supposed to be supported by the baseline version. I guess the details will be seen when the first r14 beta is out.

Comment: The Unified Headers feature seems to be out for testing now, since NDK r14 beta 1 is available. From a quick glance it seems to work pretty much as expected. But as feared, most/all the newer APIs are also hidden if you indicate that you target an older API version. Perhaps they'd be open to exposing new enums and structs even if you target an older version (to help using new APIs conditionally), but you would still need to load new functions using `dlsym` in any case.

Comment: "Simply put, Google won't tell you the earliest Android version that each APP_PLATFORM supports." The earliest Android version that each `APP_PLATFORM` supports is `APP_PLATFORM`. I have actually documented this, fwiw: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#Target-API-Set-Higher-Than-Device-API. Yes, the published docs say pretty much the opposite. I found that a week or so ago and rewriting it is in someone's task queue.

Comment: Talking about backward compatibility is tricky. No OS I can think of guarantees that a program using features only available in a newer version of the OS will be able to load on an older OS. Games using DirectX 11 will not work on Windows 98. Android doesn't treat Java any differently here. You can't use new APIs on an old device. The behavioral difference here comes from the language spec, not any policy.

Comment: `dlsym` *is* the supported way of getting new APIs with a lower target version. If you're `dlsym`ing public APIs and your app breaks on some future version of Android, that's a *bug*. Android has developer previews and beta releases. If your app is broken on a beta for this reason, we can fix it as long as it gets reported. I don't really follow the issue with `lrand48`. The issue mentioned is that you can't `dlsym` `rand` because it's an inline on older versions. So, why bother `dlsym`ing it? Just use it; it's available.

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to be a priority for the NDK team." You don't have to presume our priorities, I publish them: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/Roadmap.md#NDK-r16-NDK-Compatibility-Library. The compatibility library has been my end game for nearly two years now, there was just a lot of prerequisite things to get done before it was feasible. The compatibility library is our plan for easing the pains that are dealing with `dlsym`.

Comment: Apologies for the barrage of comments, but there was a lot of content to cover and the character limit is short (seems like comments on long answers should get a higher character count). There's actually quite a lot more to be said here, but this really isn't the venue for it, so I tried to keep my comments limited to things that could be altered or included in your answer.  tl;dr: we're working on it, but these things take time.

Comment: This is an excellent writeup and should be the first thing anyone reads that updates their NDK to a newer release and/or increases their platform levels.  I have spent countless hours on the problems Google introduced by changing stuff around in later platforms.  Even one of Google's own, in several messages I found, recommends always using the latest NDK platform.  Yeah right...don't do that.  As a rule of thumb, it seems, you should select the next level down from the min SDK, so if min sdk is 16, use NDK platform 15.  Android Studio further complicates this by forcing the platforms on you..

Comment: "Both targetSdkVersion and APP_PLATFORM must be greater than or equal to minSdkVersion." This is incorrect. APP_PLATFORM can be as low as you like. There's nothing wrong with having minSdkVersion=16 and APP_PLATFORM=android-10, it's just a bit pointless. Also android-10 does exist and is a valid value for APP_PLATFORM.

Comment: @reactive-core: "Even one of Google's own, in several messages I found, recommends always using the latest NDK platform." I've certainly never given that advice. Do our docs say that somewhere? I'd be happy to fix them. You should be using the latest NDK, but your NDK API level should be less than or equal to your minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the minimum. I am not sure what the target should represent, I think it gives some features of the target SDK but also makes sure the app will run with the minimum SDK.