# "cannot locate symbol "stpcpy"" Using QTDS driver on Android

Tags: c++, qt, android-ndk, qtsql

Hi everyone in the forum, I'm writing because i'm trying to use de QTDS driver to access a sybase database from an android devices. Reading the Qt5 Documentation I found instructions of how to build the qtds plugin, so I download the freetds library and compile it with the android NDK and copy the .so files to my project under the android/libs/armeabi-v7/freetds/lib/ directory. Also I compile the pluging for android using these .so an copy the libqsqltds.so file to the QtDir/5.5/android_armv7/plugins/sqldrivers/.

Later in the QtCreator project tag I add the library to the Build Apk Android / Additional Libraries and set the Android Build SDK to android-19.

Now when I build the project the freetds library is in the project build directory android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/freetds/lib/.

But when I run the app in the phone this error occurs:

```
dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.app.app-1/libsybdb.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "stpcpy" referenced by "libsybdb.so"...

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "stpcpy" referenced by "libsybdb.so"...
```

don't know how to include stpcpy in the project. I read on the internet that using the android SDK 19 will fix it, but it is not working.

someone know a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your `ndk-build` picked up the latest version of Android platform, **android-22**. If you expect to run on **android-19**, try  `ndk-build -B APP_PLATFORM=android-19` to rebuild the native libraries.