# dlopen fails on older Android versions

Tags: android, android-ndk, dlopen

I'm loading my native library like this at runtime

```
dlopen("mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

This works fine on recent version of android (e.g. marshmallow, nougat, etc.). However, on older versions (e.g. Jellybean), this fails with the following message in logcat

```
Failed to load mylib.so. Error: Cannot load library: 
load_library[1093]: Library 'mylib.so' not found
```

I have ensured that `mylib.so` is part of the apk. I have this as part of `x86` and `armeabi_v7a` architectures.

```
myapp.apk
- lib
  - armeabi-v7a
       mylib.so
  - x86
       mylib.so
```

As per `readelf -d mylib.so | grep NEEDED` the dependencies are

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
```

I tried loading these dependencies through `dlopen` prior to loading `mylib.so`. Though loading of those dependencies succeed, loading `mylib.so` always fails with the same error.

As mentioned before, I see this failure only on older versions of android.

How can I get this to work? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try including a slash, even if it’s just `./mylib.so`.

Comment: I tried that, same results. Looks like this needs something specific for the way older versions of android searches for the lib.

Comment: I wonder if older loaders were picky about naming. Maybe try naming your library libmylib.so instead of mylib.so. Another thing to check would be to make sure the SONAME (also part of `readelf -d` output) is correct on mylib.so.

Comment: It is already in the form of libmylib.so in my case. I just gave mylib.so as a simplified example here. So, naming isn't the reason for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to *Lollipop*, you must supply the full path to **dlopen()**. This path can be obtained in Java with `getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir`.

At any rate, you can check the contents of the **/data/data/your.package/lib** directory (sometimes it has `-1` suffix, or starts with **/data/app-lib**). This directory is world-readable, so you you should see the file **libmylib.so** there from Android Studio or `adb shell`.

Another reason for the observed behavior could be that the older device does not support **armeabi-v7a** ABI. That's easy to check with `adb shell getprop`.

Also, make sure that the library is built with the correct `APP_PLATFORM`, which should [match the minSdkVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888052/what-is-the-relation-between-app-platform-androidminsdkversion-and-androidtar).

Your library luckily does not have 'private' dependencies. But for those that do, you need to take this into account, too. Prior to *Lollipop*, these dependencies would not be loaded automatically (because the `nativeLibraryDir` was not scanned for **dlopen**). You had to load all libraries in reverse dependency order.

Comment: For users planning to use this solution, I accepted it without really trying it as I decided to stop supporting Jelly Bean for my app. If anyone finds that this solution does not work, I'll unaccept this answer. If it works also, please comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the folder name from `lib` to `jniLibs`.

Comment: Yet to get a chance to try this. After that I will update the status here.

Comment: It should be lib.