# What versions of SDK and ndk are the rigth ones for Nougat?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, buildozer

My Smartphone uses Android 7.0.

I am developing an app using buildozer on Ubuntu 18.04.

The API is 24, according to several sites.

What I don't know is which sdk and ndk version to use. I tried several versions and the outcome is different for each trial.

Using API 24, min API 9, ndk 9c, sdk 20 (buildozer.spec) I obtain the following error:

> Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=phone --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/edison/AppProjects/BESTPHONE/.buildozer/android/platform/build

There are so many errors in the log that I don't dare to put them all here.

Maybe if I know what is the right ndk and sdk version I won't need to go on  this process of trial and error.
I read many forums and none helped.
Please!

Comment: There's no "right" version of the NDK or SDK. You typically want the latest versions of both. Or at least _one of_ the latest versions, in case the latest one has bugs or incompatibilities with tools that you use.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try Virtualbox to avoid compiling problems.

Answer (score 0):

NDK r9c is ancient. It's too old to support even Android 5.

You should generally use the latest available the NDK. One NDK package supports all of the relevant API levels at the time of its release.

As for which API level you should be targeting, the answer is more complex. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21982908/632035 for a good breakdown.